# How to obtain row counts for all tables in Netezza?

Tags: system-tables, netezza

Is there a system table or view in Netezza that shows the number of records for each table?

Comment: If Netezza supports transactions, then there can't be such a view. If you have multiple transactions all deleting and inserting rows into a table at the same time, which row count should that view show you?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Many DBMSs support such a thing. The number of rows reported would depend on the isolation level, or possibly be implementation-specific; there's no logical reason such a thing can't exist just because transaction do.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
SELECT TABLENAME,
       OBJTYPE,
       OWNER,
       CREATEDATE,
       USED_BYTES,
       USED_BYTES/1073741824 as USED_GB, 
       RELTUPLES as "ROWS"
 FROM _V_TABLE_ONLY_STORAGE_STAT
 WHERE OBJCLASS = 4905 OR OBJCLASS = 4911
 ORDER BY TABLENAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this view for table
"_v_table".
and for view this 
"_v_view"

good luck

Comment: Others down-voted this answer because it is at best incomplete. The OP asked for a specific query.

Comment: "Is ther (sic) a system table/view in Netezza "