# Netezza: What schema contains all the system tables / views?

Tags: metadata, system-tables, netezza

Is there a schema I can look in or a query that I can run to see all the Netezza system or metadata tables?

I know about `_v_table`, `_v_view`, `_v_relation_column`, and `_v_groupusers`.
I know there are many others and I would like the definitive list.
Documentation on each would be nice too, but I will settle for just a list.

I looked at [How list of netezza system tables/views?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/68896) but I am looking for a list of system tables. The author of that question is looking to pull specific metadata about the tables on his system.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to access such a list via a query but IBM provide a list of [user views](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/r_sysadm_user_views.html) and [system views](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/r_sysadm_system_views.html) in their Knowledge Centre. I assume those pages are public because their website tells me I'm not currently logged in (but it's not the most user-friendly of sites in terms of authentication so I may be wrong).

As CraigBoyd pointed out in a comment, `SELECT * FROM _V_SYS_VIEW;` will give you the list of system views. `SELECT * FROM _V_VIEW;` will also list *some* of the system views plus any user-defined views. I can't tell why some views are included in `_V_SYS_VIEW` but not in `_V_VIEW`.

Comment: Hi Carl ~ thanks for this!  I look high & low and could not find it.  The link points to the system views and the last entry in the table is the key!  SELECT * FROM _V_SYS_VIEW gives a list of all the system views!  THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM _V_VIEW WHERE VIEWNAME LIKE '_V%' ORDER BY VIEWNAME:
```

Gives you all the system view names. All the view names are self descriptive.

Answer (score -2):

use the _XDB tables. some work. some dont. pity because I cant get at tables but not distribution keys, which would be useful given multiple databases with the same patterns across many

Answer (score -4):

***ADMIN*** schema contains the metadata views.